# Thread behaviour when fromCallable() and subscribeOn() in same stream

Tags: java-8, reactive-programming, publish-subscribe, project-reactor

I have created a `Mono` with `.fromCallable()` in Java spring-reactor. I thought it will run the lambda I provided asynchronously and use `Mono.empty()` as the return value. So, the execution of the entire stream would start off from a different thread.

I have 2 questions:

1. What is the execution order and number of threads if I call `.subscribeOn()` into the chain of operations?
2. Is it a good approach that I follow to check whether the response have the correct state in my below code?

   ```
   private final Scheduler myScheduler = Schedulers
                                    .newParallel("reactive-pricefetcher", 10, true);

   ...
   ...
   ...

   final Mono<Mono<Object>> callableMono = Mono
       .fromCallable(() -> {
           myHandler.updateCacheResponse(mutableObjList,
               dealsRequest.getDealParameters()
           );
           return Mono.empty();
       }) 
       .subscribeOn(myScheduler);
   callableMono.subscribe();

   boolean stillInProgress = mutableObjList.stream() 
       .anyMatch(obj -> obj.getStatus() != DONE); 

   return DealsResponse.builder()
       .complete(!stillInProgress)
       .itemDeals(mutableObjList)
       .build();
   ```

PS: I already know that using `.subscribeOn()` will move the entire stream chain into a different thread when `subscribe()` invoked.

Comment: Try to simplify your question. There is a lot of stuff here which is not clear where it's coming from and what its role like `cacheResponse` or `DealsResponse`.

Comment: @MartinTarjányi Edited the question